# Manage tabs in tosca testsuit

Tags: automation, tosca

Im trying to generate a testcase but im my web, when i click a menu this open a new tab and tosca says that cant find that element. How can i make somthing like windowshandler from selenium in tosca tricentris?

Comment: Are you saying that: In a web browser, when you click a menu item, it's opening a new web browser tab, and you need Tosca to switch to that tab and continue?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? Are you not able to scan the new tab or you face the issue while execution? If it is later, maybe the Tab title in the corresponding module has changed or the control has a dynamic ID. It's very hard to guess without further information (or maybe a screenshot if possible).

Answer (score 0):

to manage the tabs in tosca u can set a configuration parameter as "ConstraintIndex" and the value you can set as 1 in the module section
that will help you to jump the tosca from  first tab to second tab